# Java servlet request working correctly only for first of multiple auto generated html elements

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

unfortunately this is a project for school and most of the variables are in my native language, i'll translate any if needed, but leave the code as is, just in case that's somehow the problem.

I'm making a web app for a Catering Service, using Java servlets for my backend and JSP for my front end.

The session stores an Order object which has a HashMap<Product, Quantity>.
On my Cart jsp foreach Product in the hashmap there's a row in the css grid displayed on the screen.

```
<!-- Cart jsp snippet-->
                         <!--article             Order.getHashMap().keySet()-->
            <c:forEach var="stavka" items="${Narudzbina.getStavkeNarudzbine().keySet()}">
                <div class='korpa-stavka'>
                     <!-- article.getName() -->
                    <h5>${stavka.getNazivProizvoda()}</h5>
                    <input class="btn btn-light poeni-korpa" type="number" min="1" id="${stavka.getProizvodID()}" onchange="updateUrl(this)" value="${Narudzbina.getStavkeNarudzbine().get(stavka)}">
                    <div class="stavka-buttons">
                        <!-- Link is filled with a js script -->
                            <a href="" id="a${stavka.getProizvodID()}" class="btn btn-warning btn-stavka">Izmeni</a>
                            <!-- Link is static except for the ID, but no JS -->
                            <a href="Korpa?Zahtev=Izbrisi&Proizvod=${stavka.getProizvodID()}" class="btn btn-danger btn-stavka">Izbriši</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class='stavka-total'>Cena: ${stavka.getCenaPoPorciji() * Narudzbina.getStavkeNarudzbine().get(stavka)} RSD</p>
            </c:forEach>
```

This works as intended.
One of the `a` tags `href` value is filled with an onchange call from the number input before it.

```
// Js for updating href of that a tag
function updateUrl(element){
           var link = document.getElementById("a" + element.id);
           link.setAttribute("href", "Korpa?Zahtev=Izmeni&Proizvod="+ element.id +"&Kolicina=" + element.value);  
}
```

That also works well, for every auto generated row from the hashtable. Clicking on the `a` button on any of them, as far as i can see, correctly calls the "Korpa" Controller, with good parameters, different, and correct ArticleID, different and correct Quantity for each of them.

Korpa servlet then packs the session Order object in a temporary Order, calls changeQuantity(article, newQuantity) on it, when that's done packs the changed Order in session and reloads the cart page..

```
               // Order order = session order
               Narudzbina narudzbina = (Narudzbina)session.getAttribute("Narudzbina");
               //order.change quantity
               narudzbina.izmeniKolicinu(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("Proizvod")), Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("Kolicina")));
               session.setAttribute("Narudzbina",narudzbina);
               //refreshes the Cart jsp 
               response.sendRedirect("Profil?User=" + session.getAttribute("User").toString() + "&View=Korpa");
               return;
```

The Order Model just changes the value in the hash map

```
             //changeQuantity     article ID      newQuantity
   public void izmeniKolicinu(int proizvodID, int novaKolicina) {
             //Order ord : hashMap.keySet()
        for (Proizvod prod : stavkeNarudzbine.keySet()) {
            //if ord.getArticleID == articleID
            if (prod.getProizvodID() == proizvodID) {
                stavkeNarudzbine.put(prod, novaKolicina);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now all of this works perfectly well for both changing quantity and deleting the article ( deleting is almost identical and there's a switch statement in the Controller to check what to run, i ommited that since this is already a long post, and it's very likely irrelevant )

But only for the first article drawn on the cart jsp screen.
The other articles properly update their respective `href`'s, and all properly call the servlet, the page refreshes, there's no exceptions thrown, and the status of the request is 302 for both the 1st one ( that works ) and the rest. But the values do not update.

*Clicking on any but the first generated link doesn't update values*

Also if i click on Remove on the first one that actually works, it gets removed, and the new first drawn one works now.
Sorry for the rambling question, I'm just a student, really lost on this one, not really quite sure what the problem could be so I gave all the info i thought would be in any way helpful...
P.S There's no communication with the database anywhere in this process.

EDIT: Clarified problem

Comment: Could you show code how the `stavkeNarudzbine` map is initially populated? The loop in izmeniKolicinu only does something if there's already an entry for that `proizvodID`, and that might be the bug.

Comment: Only entry's from `stavkeNarudzbine` are displayed on the page and the `proizvodID` is passed automatically, there *must* be an entry always. 
Also once i delete the first one, the second, which hasn't worked before, now becomes the first and works correctly, so it's `proizvodID` was already in `stavkeNarudzbine`.
The code for populating the HashMap is completely seperate from this process, User adds something to cart on another jsp, it finds the *something* in database and populates, too much code from to add here

Comment: Just from the description of the bug: could getProizvodID() possibly be the same value for all entries?

Comment: @Simon No ID is unique for each, and correctly inserted into the url for each article ( rechecked this after your comment). 
Also while checking that i found out `izmeniKolicinu` never gets called when i click on one of the articles that dont work ( Any but the one rendered 1st on the screen).

Comment: In that case, could you show more of the controller code? Do all links at least reach the controller code, or not even that?

Comment: Damn i feel dumb, the error was i `break;` ed out of that foreach in `izmeniKolicinu` after the first iteration instead of when it found a match... Spent 4 hours on this, you suggesting that `proizvodID` probably saved me the next 4... Thanks man, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a proper answer here (the OP found it through the comments): the `break` needs to be within the if-condition

```
if (prod.getProizvodID() == proizvodID) {
    stavkeNarudzbine.put(prod, novaKolicina);
    break; // HERE
}
// NOT HERE: break;
```